# Can I get a refund for an unnecessary ESTA aplication?

Tags: usa, esta

Last year I've applied for an ESTA, on the 7th of September 2015 (Orlando). I was under the impression that I had to apply for an ESTA every year. Fortunately my application from September 2015 is still valid (until September 2017). Unfortunately I unnecessarily applied for a new one on the 14th of October (New York), thus unnecessarily paying for a new application.

Unfortunately I can not seem to find the application from September 2015. I was hoping to find out how to withdraw the application from 14th of October and adjust the details (address/destination) and get my money back from the second (unnecessary) application.

Does anyone know what I need to/can do?

Comment: Continuing our discussion from the other question...Was your new application from the 14th approved? Are you sure you got the second ESTA from the official site ([esta.cbp.dhs.gov](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/))? There are a number of imposter sites out there. If you paid more than $14, you weren't dealing with the official site.

Comment: "It states that my ESTA is valid until 27 of august 2017": does your passport by any chance expire on 27 August 2017?

Comment: Hi Phoog, thank you for your reply. AHA moment! you are correct, my passport expires on the 27th of august 2017. I feel so stupid.. And I unnecessarily applied for a new ESTA, thus paid too much, and did not connect the dots with regards to the expiration date of my passport... thank you guys!!!

Comment: if you paid more than 14$ you got scammed, thanks to payment protection laws (spain/europe) the same happened to me but my bank returned me the money and told "their" bank to return them the cash, which they did. bet they aren't happy about it.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't get a refund. The ESTA website [does mention](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/frequently-asked-questions-about-visa-waiver-program-vwp-and-electronic-system-travel) the possibility of a partial refund in case your application is refused, but nothing about being able to refund a successful application.

I presume $14 isn't a lot of money in the grand scheme of things, so I wouldn't pursue it farther.